# Meteor.call() - can it be aborted (stopped before it finishes)?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Let's say we have a grid, and the data comes from the server `Meteor.call()`. When user clicks on the pagination, or changes sorting or filtering options, some animation is shown, and the method is called. Once data comes back, we hide the animation and render the list. This works great, but we would also like to abort current call if the user changes their mind before data comes back and goes to another page, or changes another filter. Is there a way to do that? In AngularJS I used `.abort()` on ajax http requests, and that worked perfectly... is Meteor lacking a similar function?

Comment: It's Async function why don't you check when result is back for if page navigated abort or if something abort. Can't really cancel it officially

Answer (score 1):

You can use `beforeSend` option for that:

```
    var requestObject;

    HTTP.call("GET", url, {
        beforeSend: req => requestObject = req
    }, (error, result) => {
         // do your stuff ...
    });

    requestObject.abort();
```

Note: at the time of writing this is only supported on client.